# Certificate Selection with Chrome on Windows and Android

Tags: google-chrome, azure-active-directory, adfs

Our IT department recently updated the certificate of our ADFS server.

Now some of our clients get a certificate dialog, especially Windows and Android devices, if they want to access our web applications and log in via AAD/ADFS.

[image]
[image]

(Sorry, Chrome blocks screenshots in incognito)

What has our IT department forgotten or disregarded here?
How can I proceed to find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Reproduce the issue and check if the port number is getting listed as 49443, (this information is not clearly visible in the first screenshot)
If it is 49443, certificate authentication is enabled on ADFS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is port 443. nmap says 49443 is closed.